# Understanding the Leibniz formula for determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I am a programmer and trying to write the Leibniz formula for determinants into C++ code, but I am unable to fully understand it.
Can someone walk me through it?

$$\det(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_n}\text{sgn}(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{\sigma(i),i}$$

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For one, but that might be irrelevant to you, this formula is *not* the way you want to actually compute determinants; there are much more efficient methods for that. But I will try to help you understand the formula.

We have an $n \times n$-matrix $A$. Its elements are $a_{i,j}$ as usual, or $a[i,j]$ in more C-like notation.
The outer sum sums over all permutations (this set is $S_n$), so that is an outer loop. A permutation is just a reordering of the indices, like $(1,3,2)$ for $n=3$; for $n=3$ there are $3!$ permutations of the indices: $(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,1,3),(2,3,1),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)$, and for $n$ indices there are $n!$ in general. Here we can interpret this as a function: $(3,2,1)$ is the function that sends $1$ to $3$, $2$ to $2$ and $3$ to $1$, e.g. Now, each permutation has a sign $\operatorname{sgn}(\sigma)$, which is either +1 or -1. The identity has sign +1, while interchanging two elements of a permutation changes the sign to the opposite one. So $(1,3,2), (3,2,1), (2,1,3)$ are odd permutations on $n=3$, because we interchanged one pair. One can prove that half the permutations are even (have sign +1), and the other half has sign -1.

Now for each permutation $\sigma$ we take the multiplication of the elements of $A$ as specified by the permutation, interpreted as a map. So $(1,3,2)$ is the map $1 \rightarrow 1, 2 \rightarrow 3, 3 \rightarrow 2$, so we get the product $a_{1,1}a_{3,2}a_{2,3}$, where the second index is the original, the first its image under $\sigma$.

The formula says that $\det(A)$ is the sum of all such products where we consider all permutations of the index set, and the products from an odd permutation get a minus sign.

So for $n=3$ we get $$\det(A) = a_{1,1}a_{2,2}a_{3,3} - a_{1,1}a_{2,3}a_{3,2} - a_{1,3}a_{2,2}a_{3,1} - a_{1,2}a_{2,1}a_{3,3} + a_{1,2}a_{2,3}a_{3,1} + a_{1,3}a_{2,1}a_{3,2}$$ where the minus signs correspond to the odd permutations from above.

So you need algorithms to enumerate all permutations, and compute their signs, and then loop over all these products. It's quite complicated to get right, and not very efficient. But this formula allows one to prove some facts for determinants, so it has its uses.

Comment: So what is a more efficient way to calculate the determinant? Because I choose this way because I thought it was verye fficient.

Comment: @Cheiron [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination#Computing_determinants) is a fast and relatively simple way. The Leibniz formula is more of a theoretical tool, in fact it is probably one of the slowest ways to calculate the determinant.

Comment: I wanted to calculate the determinant to make sure the matrix has an inverse. If I just do gaussian (or gauss-jordan, right?), I will eventually run into a problem and have to throw an error. Right?

Comment: So, the next question is "why do you want to know if the matrix has an inverse". I hope it's not so that you can calculate the inverse, and then use it to solve systems of equations. That's a really bad way to solve systems of equations. And, you shouldn't be writing any of this stuff yourself, anyway. People with **much** more expertise than you have already written libraries to do this sort of thing, and those libraries have been battle-hardened from years of use. Don't try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Look at how this stuff is done in the "Numerical Recipes" book, for example. Their algorithms are not the best in the world, but they are better than any that you or I could write, and they're fairly simple and easy to understand.

Comment: @bubba Its a school assignment. The assignment was: write a program that can inverse a matrix. So that's what I am doing. I am also extending the assignment a bit by adding some checks, to imporve my C++ skills even more.

Comment: @Cheiron just use elimination. It's not too hard, and if a matrix is not invertible you will find out along the way.

Comment: @Cheiron -- OK. Fair enough. But the Leibnitz formula is still bad. Use elimination or LU decomposition. Then, as Henno said, you will find out during the computations that the matrix is singular (non-invertible) and you can raise an exception or return an error.